# can ajc omit a specified @Aspect class and let spring aop handle it?

Tags: aop, aspectj

My application need to use both `Aspectj` and `Spring AOP` ,  Spring AOP is convenient sometimes , but when i use `ajc` compiler , it compiles all files annotated with `@Aspectj`.

my question is : can i tell ajc to ignore a specific `Aspectj` file and let `Spring AOP` handle the `aop` job ? tried my best but failed to figure it out , so help needed ... tks advance !

---

i use gradle to manage my application , and i wrote a gradle plugin with integrate `ajc` in it .

`weaveClasses.dependsOn compileJava
 classes.dependsOn weaveClasses`

i use post compile method .

here is my gradle config , i only post the structure .

```
group 'com.test.api'
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8


ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    springVersion = '4.3.9.RELEASE'




    env = System.getProperty("env") == null ? "development" : System.getProperty("env")
}

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
        classpath "com.test.tools:aspectj-post-compile:1.1.5"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    version '0.1.7'
    group 'com.test.api'

    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }
}


subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: "aspectj.post.compile"

    version = parent.version
    group = parent.group

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        all*.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    }

    apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
    checkstyle {
        toolVersion = "7.6"
        ignoreFailures = true
        configFile file("${project.rootDir}/checkstyle/test-java.xml")
    }

    tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
        reports {
            xml.enabled = false
            html.enabled = false
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "http://maven-test.corp.yiran.com:8081/repository/maven-public/" }
        jcenter()
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDirs = ["src/main/resources/base", "src/main/resources/$env"]
            }
        }
        test {
            resources {
                srcDirs = ["src/test/resources/base", "src/test/resources/$env"]
            }
        }
    }



    [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options.collect { options ->
        options.compilerArgs.add '-parameters'
    }
    weaveClasses.dependsOn compileJava
    classes.dependsOn weaveClasses
}



project(":geneva-contract") {
    jar.archiveName = "test-contract.jar"

    dependencies {
        compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$jacksonVersion"
        compile "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
        compile "com.test.service:farmer-base:$farmerVersion"
        compile "com.test.api:daily-open-base:$dailyOpenVersion"

    }
}
```

Comment: Ajc, like any compiler, only compiles the files you tell it to compile. So it depends on how you call Ajc. You didn't mention. Do you call it directly via command line or batch file? Via Ant? Maven? Gradle? (Which plugin, if any of the previous three?) IDE? (Which one?) Please update your question, describing how you build, show your build configuration and ideally also provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Like this the question is way to unclear to answer.

Comment: @kriegaex tks for your comment , i've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put AspectJ and Spring AOP aspects into different Maven/Gradle modules and only build the AspectJ module with the AspectJ compiler, then put that module on the aspect path for the application module(s) it is to be woven into.

A more complicated way is to use an undocumented feature for compile-time weaving:

```
-xmlConfigured /path/to/my/aop-ctw.xml
```

**Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:%7E:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).

See also my [AspectJ ticket 455014](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455014) and follow the links from my comments there for further information.

A little example:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public aspect FirstAspect {
  before() : execution(* *(..)) {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public aspect SecondAspect {
  before() : execution(* *(..)) {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

If you compile and run this normally, the console log says:

```
FirstAspect: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
SecondAspect: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
```

But if you add a configuration file like this...

```xml
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="de.scrum_master.aspect.FirstAspect" />
  </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

... and then reference it from your compiler command line, e.g. like this from Eclipse with AJDT installed, ...

[image: XML configuration for AspectJ compiler]

... the console log changes to:

```
FirstAspect: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
```

Comment: now my `aspect` is automatically loaded from classpath , it's convenient and intuitive .  i want to know more about `-xmlConfigured` but i can't find it at `eclipse ajc docs` https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ajc-ref.html

Comment: Have you not read the ticket I linked to? I created it **because** it is undocumented, but linked off a couple of resources where you find information, such as mailing list post, scattered mentions in release notes etc. Sorry, but if you don't read the resources I am providing I cannot help you.

Comment: BTW, you said it is working according to my answer for you, so I would appreciate if you accepted and upvoted the answer.

Comment: i've seen your ticket ,  u must have spent lots of hard work on it ! tks your , it would be better if you make it more portable and easy to use , like a plugin in maven or grandle.

Comment: I do not use Gradle, but as for Maven there is support for that option is [AspectJ Maven plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#xmlConfigured).

Comment: **Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:~:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).